# How to calculate a global strain from a field disitribution

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, deformation

For an arbitrary articulated structure subject to non-affine (non homogeneous) deformations, the components of the strain tensor are defined locally. Is there a way to calculate a numerical strain tensor that represents the whole volume? Can a Poisson's ratio be determined for such situation?

My first guess is that the volume average of the fields should do it, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: certainly you can calculate a volume average strain.  The question Is that a relevant/representative measure depends on how non-uniform it is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically, I want the Poisson's ratio of the structure.

Comment: poissons ratio is a material property. It is not a property of a structure.

Comment: OK, what I want is the ratio between the axial and the longitudinal strains, for the whole structure.